# django comparing datetime.now with pub_date

Tags: python, django, view

```
class event_archive(models.Model):
event_id            = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
date_submitted      = models.DateTimeField()
event_start_time    = models.DateTimeField()
event_end_time      = models.DateTimeField()
event_closed        = models.BooleanField()
```

I want to do this : Here is the pseudo_code:

---

```
event = event_archive.objects.all()
for e in event:
if event_start_time > datetime_now()
    print "upcoming";
elif event_start_time < datetime_now() < event_end_time
    print "now";
elif event_end_time < datetime_now() < **24 hours passed the event ends**
    print "%d hours ago",%hour;
elif event_end_time < datetime_now() > **24 hours passed the event ends** and event_end_time < datetime_now() < **48 hours passed the event ends**
    print "yesterday";
else
    print "recorded"
endif;
endfor;
```

---

** I am very new in programming and python..Please dont mind if I asked very silly question or does not put the question clearly..In the bold line I am not sure what should I use??

I need help to write my django view function..Any help please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this for a template, use the [`timeuntil`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timeuntil) and [`timesince`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timesince) filters which are designed for this task.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

if some_datetime > datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=10):
    return "some_date is greater than the current datetime plus 10 days"
```

See timedelta doc: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_now = datetime.now()
```

'datetime_now' variable now has the current time.

Use this variable to compare with event start time and print or do relevant stuff for that condition.

for eg:

```
if event_start_time > datetime_now:
  print "upcoming"
```

Comment: I am stuck in the elif condition:ex:elif event_end_time < datetime_now() < **24 hours passed the event ends**
    print "%d hours ago",%hour;